# how to download ed2k with command?

Tags: downloads

The ed2k is :  ed2k://|file|test.iso|1643802624|A3058CE4F2AD70356D07AAA5|/

I want to save the iso in /home .

How can i write command to download the ed2k into  /home/test.iso with amule or mldonkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this command:

`ed2k` - [aMule eD2k link parser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ed2k.1.html)

and it comes with the `amule-utils` package

```
sudo apt install amule-utils
```

if you have a list ed2k links (separated by newlines) from emule or other client you can just use `xargs`:

```
cat links.txt | xargs -L1 ed2k
```

For this to work `amule` or `amuled` need to be already started, you will see the files were added in the `aMule Log` tab

BTW if you have `'` (single quotes) characters in the `ed2k` link you need to replace them with escaped once `\'`

Comment: If you come from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and cannot use this command to install amule-utils, you may refer to this link http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/install-amule-ubuntu-20-04-lts/